# Select only one record for each match

Tags: sql, ms-access, coldfusion

Let's see if I can explain this properly.

I am (unfortunately) using Access.

I have a table as such:

```
Date       |  ResID  |  Med    |  time   |  emar  |
___________+_________+_________+_________+________|
11/18/2010 |      72 | Aspirin | 8:00 AM | 427    |
11/19/2010 |      72 | Aspirin | 8:00 AM | 427    |
11/20/2010 |      72 | Aspirin | 8:00 AM | 427    |
11/18/2010 |      72 | Aspirin | 2:00 PM | 427    |
11/19/2010 |      72 | Aspirin | 2:00 PM | 427    |
11/20/2010 |      72 | Aspirin | 2:00 PM | 427    |
11/18/2010 |      73 | Aspirin | 7:00 AM | 428    |
11/19/2010 |      73 | Aspirin | 7:00 AM | 428    |

...etc
```

I know this could be set up much better, but unfortunately this is all I have with which to work.

How could I query this database such that it would return only one row for each matching set of ResID, Med, Time and emar? So the result I'm looking for from this example would be:

```
Date       |  ResID  |  Med    |  time   |  emar  |
___________+_________+_________+_________+________|
11/18/2010 |      72 | Aspirin | 8:00 AM | 427    |
11/18/2010 |      72 | Aspirin | 2:00 PM | 427    |
11/18/2010 |      73 | Aspirin | 7:00 AM | 428    |
```

The date doesn't matter except that it must be in a specified range: `date_min` to `date_max`. This is in ColdFusion if it makes a difference.

Comment: In the result set you're looking for, what is the purpose of displaying the first column (Date) if it doesn't mater?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(Date) AS Date, ResID, Med, time, emar
from YourTable
WHERE Date > date_min and Date < date_max /*Might need >= and <= if inclusive*/
GROUP BY  ResID, Med, time, emar
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write something like:

```
Select * from TABLENAME where date>date('xxxx-xx-xx') and date<('xxxx-xx-xx')
```

where it says 'xxxx-xx-xx' you should write something like 2010-11-30